# Combining data from multiple tables into a single column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

My current output from table A looks like this:

```
id  event        timestamp              registered acct_add funded applied 
1   Register     5/18/2018 4:00:00 AM   1         0         0      0 
1   AddAccount   5/18/2018 5:00:00 AM   0         1         0      0
1   Funded       5/18/2018 6:00:00 AM   0         0         1      0 
2   Register     5/18/2018 7:00:00 AM   1         0         0      0
2   AddAccount   5/18/2018 8:00:00 AM   0         1         0      0
2   Funded       5/18/2018 9:00:00 AM   0         0         1      0
```

The values for `event` are supposed to be:

```
'Register', 
'AddAccount',
'Funded',
'Applied'(*)
```

It turns out that until a certain date, the last event wasn't firing. However, Table B has two columns: `id`, `application_date`, and can be transformed into:

```
id  application_date       applied 
1   5/18/2018 6:30:00 AM   1         
2   5/18/2018 9:30:00 AM   1
```

In reality my query is a combination of 5+ tables with 100+ lines of code, so can you please suggest how can I can combine the two tables to include one view **preferably without a union** such that:

```
id  event        timestamp              registered acct_add funded applied 
1   Register     5/18/2018 4:00:00 AM   1         0         0      0 
1   AddAccount   5/18/2018 5:00:00 AM   0         1         0      0
1   Funded       5/18/2018 6:00:00 AM   0         0         1      0 
1   Applied      5/18/2018 6:30:00 AM   0         0         0      1 
2   Register     5/18/2018 7:00:00 AM   1         0         0      0
2   AddAccount   5/18/2018 8:00:00 AM   0         1         0      0
2   Funded       5/18/2018 9:00:00 AM   0         0         1      0 
2   Applied      5/18/2018 9:30:00 AM   0         0         0      1
```

Thank you!

Comment: To me a `union all` seems like the natural solution to this problem. Why don't you want a union? Performance, writing complexity, other?

Comment: @TheImpaler in actuality, when I say a given table has any # of columns, that's more like 5+ tables will allow me to get to that (like position table to be combined with account table to be combined with goal table to be combined with user table to get user id, and then combine with another table to get applied_at, now union that with another query of 5+ tables)

Comment: For simplicity you could create a view that produces `table_a`, then all queries will be short and simple using that view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tweak upon The Impaler's answer to stage Table B in the same order as Table A, single quote hard text, and revise the last 0 to a 1 in order to indicate that the ID is affirmatively applied.

```
select * from (
  select * from table_a
  union all select id, 'Applied', application_date,  0, 0, 0, 1 from table_b
  ) all_rows
order by id, timestamp;
```

I would have offered this as a comment to your answer, but I can't comment yet.

Comment: Deleting my answer so you'll get the votes -- it doesn't allow me to delete the "accepted answer".

Answer (score 1):

Using a `union all` the solution looks pretty simple:

```
select * from (
  select * from table_a
  union all select id, 'Applied', application_date,  0, 0, 0, 1 from table_b
  ) all_rows
order by id, timestamp;
```

Comment: Improved answer according @user9824134 answer.